# Cannot find type definition file for 'node' error in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, model-view-controller

I am new in Anguar2. I am working on MVC Core. When I am trying to run my application after debugging, I can view the screen but after few seconds I am getting the following error:

**"in E:\Websites2017\MVC\MVC6\Angular2ASPCORE\Angular2ASPCORE\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(1,23): error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'."**

In the browser inspection tool I have got this information:

[image]

I have tried to restore package.json file but got an error like "**Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.**". I have cleared the temp  folder and executed install npm command from Powershell as an administrator but result was same.

The package.json fie is like below:

```
{
  "name": "Angular2Spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.10",
    "angular2-universal": "~2.0.10",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.0.10",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^1.0.6",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
  }
}
```

Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Thanks

Partha

Answer (score 0):

Delete node_modules folder and run following command again

```
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Comment: upgrade ts-node to v3.1.0

Comment: I have tried "npm install -g ts-node" from PM tool and it automatically install ts-node v4.x.xx but that was not working. Then I also tried "npm install -g typescript". Nothing is working :(

Comment: which version of angular you are using

Comment: Install node type definition file seperately npm install --save @types/node

Comment: Application is running well with IE but the problem arises when I use Chrome.  The java script error in the browser is like                                     : "n E:\Websites2017\MVC\MVC6\Angular2ASPCORE\Angular2ASPCORE\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-http.d.ts
(5,22): error TS2415: Class 'PreloadHttp' incorrectly extends base class 'Http'.
  Types of property 'request' are incompatible.". I am using angular2.

Comment: @Partha : You are running the application by pressing visual studio F5 button or manually typing the url in broswer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162223/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-partha).

Comment: By pressing F5.